# Android studio приложение вылетает при запуске

Tags: java, android, android-studio

При компиляции приложение почему-то вылетает. Я только первый месяц работаю в Android Studio и сейчас начал разбираться c navigation drawer. Буду очень благодарен за советы и помощь в решении проблемы.

> 05-18 05:20:45.238 14998-14998/com.example.jone1.navig
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.example.jone1.navig, PID: 14998
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.jone1.navig/com.example.jone1.navig.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                at
>   com.example.jone1.navig.MainActivity.onPostCreate(MainActivity.java:106)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1200)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2688)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)  05-18
>   05:20:49.824 14998-14998/com.example.jone1.navig I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 14998 SIG: 9

manifests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jone1.navig">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main5Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main5" />
        <activity android:name=".Main6Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main7Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.jone1.navig;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    // Убедитесь, что используется версия
    // android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.

    // android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle устарел.
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final NavigationView nvDrawer;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Установить Toolbar для замены ActionBar'а.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Найти наш view drawer'а
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // Настроить view drawer'а
        // Найти наш view drawer'а
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Настроить view drawer'а
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    }
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        // Примечание: Убедитесь, что вы передаёте допустимую ссылку
        // на toolbar
        // ActionBarDrawToggle() не предусматривает в ней
        // необходимости и не будет отображать иконку гамбургера без
        // неё
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }
    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Создать новый фрагмент и задать фрагмент для отображения
        // на основе нажатия на элемент навигации
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = Main5Activity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = Main6Activity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = Main7Activity.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Вставить фрагмент, заменяя любой существующий
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Выделение существующего элемента выполнено с помощью
        // NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Установить заголовок для action bar'а
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Закрыть navigation drawer
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Синхронизировать состояние переключения после того, как
        // возникнет onRestoreInstanceState
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Передать любые изменения конфигурации переключателям
        // drawer'а
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    // ...
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Действие home/up action bar'а должно открывать или закрывать drawer.
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Main5Activity(код Main6Activity, Main7Activity выглядит примерно также):
    package com.example.jone1.navig;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Main5Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);
    }

}
```

Все делал по примеру взятому с этого [сайта](https://medium.com/@cryptograph2013/navigation-drawer-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-android-java%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B-a4d881a04e78)

Comment: Вы наверное забыли код приложить к вопросу.

Comment: @0xdb Код добавил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `onPostCreate` вызывается `drawerToggle.syncState()`, но при этом вы нигде не инициализируете `drawerToggle`, там всегда `null`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, теперь приложение запускается, но после перехода на фрагменты происходит вылет. Сейчас пытаюсь исправить.